Should I send an email thanking a professor or would they be bothered there's no other content?
If I send an email to ask a professor for a PhD position, and the professor replies, do need I need to reply with something like "Thanks very much for your concern", "Thanks very much for your reply" to him/her?
I am afraid if I don't reply, the professor will think I am rude (in my country, students should reply to the professor even with "yes, thank you Professor" to end the chat, since if the last sentence was written by the professor, it would be considered impolite to not respond). But I don't want to bother the professor with this spam-like email.
The professor is from a western culture (US or Europe). Do I need to reply?
